# How to check array data that matches from random characters in php?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array like below:

```
$fruits = array("apple","orange","papaya","grape")
```

I have a variable like below:

```
$content = "apple";
```

I need to filter some condition like: if this variable matches at least one of the array elements, do something. The variable, `$content`, is a bunch of random characters that is actually one of these available in the array data like below:

```
$content = "eaplp"; // it's a dynamically random char from the actual word "apple`
```

what have I done was like the below:

```
$countcontent = count($content);

for($a=0;$a==count($fruits);$a++){

      $countarr = count($fruits[$a]);

      if($content == $fruits[$a] && $countcontent == $countarr){
          echo "we got".$fruits[$a];
      }

}
```

I tried to count how many letters these phrases had and do like `if...else...` when the total word in string matches with the total word on one of array data, but is there something that we could do other than that?

Comment: How do you want to handle the situation when more than one word can be mapped to the random letters array?

Comment: for my situation, i just need to search only one word from the whole word inside an array, because there is only one the word that matches with the random word  @sevavietl, there is no multiple word that similar like `apple custard` , `apple pie` . Only `apple`.

Comment: `in_array()` ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can check if an array contains some value with `in_array`. So you can check if your `$fruits` array contains the string `"apple"` with,

```
in_array("apple", $fruits)
```

which returns a boolean.

If the order of the letters is random, we can sort the string alphabetically with this function:

```
function sorted($s) {
    $a = str_split($s);
    sort($a);
    return implode($a);
}
```

Then map this function to your array and check if it contains the sorted string.

```
$fruits = array("apple","orange","papaya","grape");
$content = "eaplp";
$inarr = in_array(sorted($content), array_map("sorted", $fruits));

var_dump($inarr);
//bool(true)
```

---

Another option is `array_search`. The benefit from using `array_search` is that it returns the position of the item (if it's found in the array, else `false`).

```
$pos = array_search(sorted($content), array_map("sorted", $fruits));

echo ($pos !== false) ? "$fruits[$pos] found." : "not found.";  
//apple found.
```

Comment: How do i echo the result like "apple found" or " papaya found" ? I know tgat the result will be "true" but how do i echo the real words? I mean not the random character that were given

Comment: You'll have to loop over the array or use `array_search`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This will also work but in a slightly different manner.

I split the strings to arrays and sort them to match eachoter.
Then I use array_slice to only match the number of characters in `$content`, if they match it's  a match.
This means this will match in a "loose" way to with "apple juice" or "apple curd".

Not sure this is wanted but figured it could be useful for someone.

```
$fruits = array("apple","orange","papaya","grape","apple juice", "applecurd");
$content = "eaplp";
$content = str_split($content);
$count = count($content);

Foreach($fruits as $fruit){
    $arr_fruit = str_split($fruit);
    // sort $content to match order of $arr_fruit
    $SortCont = array_merge(array_intersect($arr_fruit, $content), array_diff($content, $arr_fruit));
    // if the first n characters match call it a match
    If(array_slice($SortCont, 0, $count) == array_slice($arr_fruit, 0, $count)){
        Echo "match: " . $fruit ."\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
match: apple
match: apple juice
match: applecurd
```

https://3v4l.org/hHvp3
It is also comparable in speed with t.m.adams answer. Sometimes faster sometimes slower, but note how this code can find multiple answers. https://3v4l.org/IbuuD

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clean approach. Returns unscrambled value early if found, otherwise returns null. Only returns an exact match.

```
function sortStringAlphabetically($stringToSort)
{
    $splitString = str_split($stringToSort);
    sort($splitString);

    return implode($splitString);
}

function getValueFromRandomised(array $dataToSearch = [], $dataToFind)
{
    $sortedDataToFind = sortStringAlphabetically($dataToFind);

    foreach ($dataToSearch as $value) {
        if (sortStringAlphabetically($value) === $sortedDataToFind) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$fruits = ['apple','orange','papaya','grape'];
$content = 'eaplp';

$dataExists = getValueFromRandomised($fruits, $content);

var_dump($dataExists);
// string(5) "apple"
```

Not found example:

```
$content = 'eaplpo';
var_dump($dataExists);
// NULL
```

---

Then you can use it (eg) like this:

```
echo !empty($dataExists) ? $dataExists . ' was found' : 'No match found';
```

NOTE: This is case sensitive, meaning it wont find "Apple" from "eaplp". That can be resolved by doing `strtolower()` on the loop's condition vars.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the simplest way to answer that question. some of the algorithm above seems to be "overkill".

```
$fruits = array("apple","orange","papaya","grape");
$content = "eaplp";

    foreach ($fruits as $key => $fruit) {
        $fruit_array = str_split($fruit); // split the string into array
        $content_array = str_split($content); // split the content into array

        // check if there's no difference between the 2 new array
        if ( sizeof(array_diff($content_array, $fruit_array)) === 0 ) {
            echo "we found the fruit at key: " . $key;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: now this one is really nice! array_diff().. didnt think of this one :)

Comment: @Bernhard thanks, there's no need to complicate things and its really more readable. :)

Answer (score 4):

What about using only native PHP functions.

```
$index = array_search(count_chars($content), array_map('count_chars', $fruits));
```

If `$index` is not null you will get the position of `$content` inside `$fruits`.

P.S. Be aware that `count_chars` might not be the fastest approach to that problem.

Answer (score 4):

With a random token to search for a value in your array, you have a **problem with false positives**. That can give misleading results depending on the use case.

On search cases, for example wrong typed words, I would implement a filter solution which produces a matching array. One could sort the results by calculating the [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) distance to fetch the most likely result, if necessary.

**String length solution**

Very easy to implement.

*False positives*: Nearly every string with the same length like `apple` and `grape` would match.

*Example*:

```
$matching = array_filter($fruits, function ($fruit) use ($content) {
    return strlen($content) == strlen($fruit);
});
if (count($matching)) {
    // do your stuff...
}
```

**Regular expression solution**

It compares string length and in a limited way containing characters. It is moderate to implement and has a good performance on big data cases.

*False positives*: A content like `abc` would match `bac` but also `bbb`.

*Example*:

```
$matching = preg_grep(
     '#['.preg_quote($content).']{'.strlen($content).'}#',
      $fruits
);
if (count($matching)) {
    // do your stuff...
}
```

**Alphanumeric sorting solution**

Most accurate but also a slow approach concerning performance using PHP.

*False positives*: A content like `abc` would match on `bac` or `cab`.

*Example*:

```
$normalizer = function ($value) {
    $tokens = str_split($value);
    sort($tokens);
    return implode($tokens);
};
$matching = array_filter($fruits, function ($fruit) use ($content, $normalizer) {
    return ($normalizer($fruit) == $normalizer($content));
});
if (count($matching)) {
    // do your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about looping through the array, and using a flag to see if it matches?

```
$flag = false;

foreach($fruits as $fruit){
    if($fruit == $content){
        $flag = true;
    }
}

if($flag == true){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: the $content is a random char... so this thing is works, but it's looks really similar with my tried..

Answer (score 3):

I like t.m.adams answer but I also have a solution for this issue:

**array_search_random(string $needle, array $haystack [, bool $strictcase = FALSE ]);**

Description: Searches a string in array elements regardless of the position of the characters in the element.

- needle: the caracters you are looking for as a string
- haystack: the array you want to search
- strictcase: if set to TRUE needle 'mood' will match 'mood' and 'doom' but not 'Mood' and 'Doom', if set to FALSE (=default) it will match all of these.

Function:

```
 function array_search_random($needle, $haystack, $strictcase=false){

  if($strictcase === false){
   $needle = strtolower($needle);     
  }

  $needle = str_split($needle);
            sort($needle);
  $needle = implode($needle);

  foreach($haystack as $straw){

   if($strictcase === false){
    $straw = strtolower($straw);     
   }

   $straw = str_split($straw);
            sort($straw);
   $straw = implode($straw);

   if($straw == $needle){
    return true;
   }

  }

  return false;

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

if(in_array("apple", $fruits)){
true  statement
}else{
else statement
}

Comment: please edit your answer and add more description, and please use the correct markup code for a script